# Как удалить пустые поля в метабоксе WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Проблема заключается в следующем.

В записи есть метабокс "доп литература" и поля с названием и ссылкой.
Как можно при сохранении сделать проверку на пустые строки и удалить их?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал delete_post_meta, но не помогло. Подскажите хотя бы, в какую сторону смотреть.

```
<?php $documents = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'book_docs'); ?>

                            <?php if (is_array($documents)): ?>
                                <?php $documents_count = count($documents); ?>

                                <?php if ($documents_count > 1): ?>
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <button>
                                            Книги
                                            
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-collapse">
                                            <?php foreach ($documents as $b): ?>
                                                <?php $b = json_decode($b, true); ?>

                                                <?php if (!is_empty($b['link'])): ?>
                                                    <?php if ($b['name'] == '') {
$b['name'] = $b['link'];
```

} ?>

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: добавил в пост  выше

Comment: Если поля  пустые - они и так не пишутся.  Или я не понял вопрос?

Comment: суть, чтобы в админке пустые строки пропали. Это вообще возможно?

Comment: Ну тогда js в руки и скрывать. Только смысл? А если понадобиться добавить/изменить? ИМХО странная какая-то затея... И когда тут к кому-то обращаешься   - пиши ник через @ - тогда человек получит уведомление. что ты ему написал. Иначе он не узнает, что ты ему написал если специально  не зайдёт в твоё вопрос.

Comment: точно, через js. Клиент так хочет (((   Про @ ник - спасибо, не знал